# issues .htaccess: No input file specified

Tags: php, cakephp

Someone can help me with this? I've got Apache/2.4.39 + PHP 7.3.6 and Windows 10 x64 installed on my machine. I've already check if my rewrite is enable too. Actually i have this code in my .htaccess and works fine.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've already tried anothers configurations like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But no success.

Someone have any idea??

Comment: try to setting RewriteBase /

Comment: No success too =/

Comment: Excuse me, but what is your purpose? Recover a GET variable or do you want all GET requests to always point to the index?

Comment: I want all requests pointing to the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that all request point to the index, you htaccess is a little bit incorrect.

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but I got the same error. I've already check my Nginx configuration and is works fine. I dont know what can be anymore.

Comment: No. Im trying up my api to a server. The server use just nginx. Im my machine i use Apache.